# Asynhronus, Multithread simulation of real life process

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

first of all I have to mention I'm not a programmer but a mechanical engineer so please don't crucify me if I misinterpret something or say some nonsense.

I want to write a python code witch will be "simulating" a real life problem. The real life problem is something like FIFO queue, where objects are taken from on different stations and they spend there some time and then they are returned back to queue.

What I understand what I need is to write an asynchronous Programm, because I have one Function which is putting objects to queue (let say every 15 second) and then I have some stations which take only one object from this queue and then are working on it for some time again (simple timer and a print "Hi im working on object x, will return it in:  minutes".

I'm not sure if I can do it with Threading? What if I had 100 stations which work asynchronous is it possible to start 100 Threads? Because as I understand every thread should have one timer?

I would ask to give me a little push to the simplest direction to solve it, it doesn't have to be pretty but functional and easy for me.

thank you in advance for each idea!
Best regards,
MM.

Comment: Sounds like `threading` will work just fine for what you want. The downside of threading in cpython is that only 1 thread can actually be running python code at a time. But if your 'worker' processes are just simulating work by `time.sleep`ing then you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use Threading to run several processes simultaneously.

You have to create a class like this :

```
from threading import Thread

class Work(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self): # This function launch the thread
        (your code)
```

if you want run several thread at the same time :

```
def foo():
    i = 0
    list = []
    while i < 10:
        list.append(Work())
        list[i].start() # Start call run() method of the class above.
        i += 1
```

Be careful if you want to use the same variable in several threads. You must lock this variable so that they do not all reach this variable at the same time. Like this :

```
lock = threading.Lock()
lock.acquire()
try:
    yourVariable += 1 # When you call lock.acquire() without arguments, block all variables until the lock is unlocked (lock.release()).
finally:
    lock.release()
```

From the main thread, you can call join() on the queue to wait until all pending tasks have been completed.

This approach has the benefit that you are not creating and destroying threads, which is expensive. The worker threads will run continuously, but will be asleep when no tasks are in the queue, using zero CPU time.

I hope it will help you.